# почему GPT-3 от openAi пишет полный бред, и отвечает на свои же сообщения?

Tags: python, telethon

Суть проблемы:
Решил я значит поселить на аккаунт телеграма GPT-3 нейронку, чтоб за меня на сообщения отвечала. Использовал `telethon` и `openai`. Код мне помогал писать собственно сам chatGPT, по тому что в питоне я не силён.

И вот после нескольких часов мук он начал отвечать на сообщения, но...

Но пишет он либо бред, либо ничего и крашится.
Первостепенная проблема это то, что он начинает отвечать на собственные сообщения;
то есть я написал сообщение, он на него ответил обрубленным текстом, затем получил это же сообщение и ответил на него снова, и так до тех пор пока не крашнется из за `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MessageTooLongError: Message was too long (caused by SendMessageRequest)`

Когда я говорю "Бред" вот что я имею ввиду: [image: ...]
и да, ответа в чат он не отправил, он просто спамил *"The sum of the squares of the first and last numbers is equal to the square of the sum of the squares of the first and last numbers."* пока сообщение не стало слишком длинным

потом я написал ему *"hello"*
на что он мне ответил *"@tokyo_tokyo"*, продублировав это больше 10 раз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и, в качестве проявления своих высоких когнитивных способностей, начал читать собственное сообщение и придумывать на него ответ.

Но я закончил мучения бедолаги кнопкой abort

А теперь ближе к делу,
вот код программы

```
import openai
from telethon import TelegramClient

# api телеграма
api_id = 12345678
api_hash = '1234567890abc1234567890abc123456'
# api openai
openai.api_key = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890a"

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("Client started")


async def main():
    print("Ожидание сообщения...")

    async def handle_messages(f):
        if f.message is not None:
            text = f.message.strip()
            print(f)

            response = openai.Completion.create(
                engine="babbage",
                prompt=text,
                max_tokens=1024,
                temperature=0.5
            )

            print(response)
            response_text = response['choices'][0]['text']  # Extract text from the response dictionary
            print(response_text)
            await client.send_message(f.chat, response_text)

    async with client:
        async for message in client.iter_messages(entity='@QueenDek1m'):
            await handle_messages(message)

with client:
    while True:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

и ответ на сообщение *"Привет"*

```
Client started
Ожидание сообщения...
Message(id=89, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=1693638667), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 16, 22, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='привет', out=False, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, pinned=False, noforwards=False, from_id=None, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None, reactions=None, restriction_reason=[], ttl_period=None)
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": " \u043c\u0430\u043c\u0435! \u0421\u0435\u0439\u0447\u0430\u0441 \u043d\u0430\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u043f\u043e\u0437\u043d\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f. \u041d\u0435 \u0437\u0440\u044f \u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0433\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043b\u0438 \u043e \u0442\u043e\u043c, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043c\u044b \u0438\u043c\u0435\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u043b\u043e \u0441 \u0433\u043e\u0441\u0443\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\u043c \u0421\u0428\u0410, \u0438 \u0442\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043c\u044b \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u044b \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u044f\u0442\u044c \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043d\u0430\u0448\u0438\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432 \u0438 \u0446\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0439. \u042f \u043f\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0434\u0430\u044e \u043f\u043e\u0434 \u043d\u043e\u0433\u0438 \u0438 \u0443\u0445\u043e\u0436\u0443 \u0432 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0448\u043b\u043e\u0435. \u0412 \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f \u043c\u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0448\u043b\u043e\u0441\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e\u044f\u043d\u043d\u043e \u043f\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0434 \u043d\u043e\u0433\u0438 \u0438 \u0432 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0448\u043b\u043e\u0435. \u0412\u043e\u0442 \u0442\u0430\u043a \u0438 \u043d\u0430\u0447\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0442\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432\u0441\u0451 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u043a\u043e\u0433\u0434\u0430 \u043d\u0430 \u0443\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u043e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044c \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u043e\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0439, \u0438 \u044f \u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430\u043a \u043d\u0435 \u043c\u043e\u0433\u0443 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0432\u0430\u043c \u043c\u043e\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438. \u0412\u043e\u0442 \u044d\u0442\u043e \u043c\u043e\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438. \u042f \u0434\u0443\u043c\u0430\u044e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043c\u044b \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u044b \u0441\u0435\u0439\u0447\u0430\u0441 \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044e \u0432 \u0421\u0428\u0410 \u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u0442\u0435\u043c\u0443 \u00ab\u0421\u0428\u0410 \u043a\u0430\u043a \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043c\u00bb. \u0412\u0430\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043d\u044f\u0442\u044c, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043c\u044b \u0441\u0443\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u043c \u043d\u0430 \u043e\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043c\u0430, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043a \u043c\u044b \u043d\u0430\u0437\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0435\u043c \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0438 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b. \u041d\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0438\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0446\u0438\u043f\u043e\u0432, \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0446\u0438\u043f\u044b, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0435 \u043c\u044b \u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0435\u043c \u0432\u0430\u0436\u043d\u044b\u043c\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043d\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b. \u0412\u044b \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u044b \u043f\u043e\u043d\u044f\u0442\u044c, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043c, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043a \u043c\u044b \u043d\u0430\u0437\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0435\u043c \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0438 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b. \u0412\u0430\u043c \u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e \u043f\u043e\u043d\u044f\u0442\u044c, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0432 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043c, \u0430"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1672676537,
  "id": "cmpl-6UHrlK4g3AyuYfwwUyncb7QrUzllb",
  "model": "babbage",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 1023,
    "prompt_tokens": 7,
    "total_tokens": 1030
  }
}
 маме! Сейчас нам придется просто познакомиться. Не зря мы разговаривали о том, что мы имеем дело с государством США, и то, что мы должны предпринять для обеспечения наших прав и целей. Я попадаю под ноги и ухожу в прошлое. В свое время мне пришлось постоянно попадать под ноги и в прошлое. Вот так и начинается то, что на меня приходит всё время, когда на улице происходит очень большой трагический случай, и я никак не могу просто представить вам мое представление о ситуации. Вот это мое представление о ситуации. Я думаю, что мы должны сейчас посмотреть на ситуацию в США и на тему «США как страна поддерживает ислам». Вам придется понять, что мы существуем на основе ислама, а не как мы называем ваши страны. Нет никаких общих принципов, только такие принципы, которые мы считаем важными для нашей страны. Вы должны понять, что в стране принимается ислам, а не как мы называем ваши страны. Вам необходимо понять, что в стране принимается ислам, а
Ожидание сообщения...
Message(id=90, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=1693638667), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 16, 22, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='маме! Сейчас нам придется просто познакомиться. Не зря мы разговаривали о том, что мы имеем дело с государством США, и то, что мы должны предпринять для обеспечения наших прав и целей. Я попадаю под ноги и ухожу в прошлое. В свое время мне пришлось постоянно попадать под ноги и в прошлое. Вот так и начинается то, что на меня приходит всё время, когда на улице происходит очень большой трагический случай, и я никак не могу просто представить вам мое представление о ситуации. Вот это мое представление о ситуации. Я думаю, что мы должны сейчас посмотреть на ситуацию в США и на тему «США как страна поддерживает ислам». Вам придется понять, что мы существуем на основе ислама, а не как мы называем ваши страны. Нет никаких общих принципов, только такие принципы, которые мы считаем важными для нашей страны. Вы должны понять, что в стране принимается ислам, а не как мы называем ваши страны. Вам необходимо понять, что в стране принимается ислам, а', out=True, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, pinned=False, noforwards=False, from_id=PeerUser(user_id=5807726618), fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None, reactions=None, restriction_reason=[], ttl_period=None)
дальше он пытается ответить на своё же сообщение, но я его стопаю
```

прошу сильно не бить, и по возможности подсказать что я делаю не так

Comment: "Код помогал писать сам ChatGPT". Корень проблемы, ожидаемо, в этом. Эта дрянь не подходит для чего-либо серьёзного или точного. Рекомендую переписать на том языке, который более-менее знаешь и можешь сделать там это без помощи ChatGPT.

Comment: но суть в том что оно работает
не очень стабильно, но работает
проще подправить косяки, чем переписывать целиком

Comment: И? ChatGPT часто выдает то, что "работает", но работает  действительности некорректно. Оно для точных действий ( написание кода, снова же ) не подходит.

Comment: я только структуру кода у него взял
и некоторые фрагменты,
остальное сам

Comment: + ко всему, код целостный, функцию свою выполняет.
не совсем правильно, но выполняет.

я и прошу помочь поправить это "не совсем"

Comment: кстати вот
https://habr.com/ru/company/dododev/blog/708248/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="babbage",
            prompt=text,
            max_tokens=1024,
            temperature=0.5
        )
```

Babbage — это одна из самых тупых моделей в линейке GPT-3: Ada, Babbage, Curie, Davinci. Davinci — основа современной GPT-3.5-Turbo с 175B параметров в ChatGPT, а Babbage — сверхтупая модель с 1.3B параметров. Чтобы получить адекватный ответ, надо использовать модель `text-davinci-003`.

Ещё лучше перейти с `Completion` на `ChatCompletion` с моделью `gpt-3.5-turbo`, но тогда надо будет переписать запрос, потому что в этом режиме надо передавать список сообщений, а не голый текст.

Кроме того, температуру можно сделать и повыше, в районе 0.7.

P.S. ChatGPT про этот API не знает, поэтому спрашивать имеет смысл разве что модели с доступом в Интернет, например, Bing Chat (GPT-4-32k).